# PowerShell не может найти сборку

Tags: c#, powershell, рефлексия

У меня есть скрипт который читает файл и запускает его.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load($ba).EntryPoint.Invoke($null, $null)
```

Эта строка выдает ошибку:

Исключение при вызове "Invoke" с "2" аргументами: "Невозможно загрузить файл или сборку "System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" или о
дин из зависимых от них компонентов. Не удается найти указанный файл."
строка:7 знак:65
+ $asm = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load($ba).EntryPoint.Invoke <<<< ($null, $null)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodTargetInvocation

Как ее можно исправить?

Comment: Вы используете PowerShell v2 и хотите загружать сборки из .NET  Framework 4?

Comment: Это можно исправить только перекомпилировав сборку в версию 2?

Comment: Можно использовать PowerShell v3+. Или можно подсунуть конфигурационный файл, который изменит версию CLR, подгружаемую `powershell.exe`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если требуется перевести `PowerShell` второй версии на "рельсы" .NET Framework 4, можно, как уже было написано в комментарии к вопросу, в папке с `powershell.exe` (обычно это `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\`) создать файл `powershell.exe.config` следующего содержания:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<configuration> 
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319"/> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/> 
    </startup> 
</configuration>
```

После [пере]запуска хоста `PowerShell` посмотреть на вывод команды `$PSVersionTable`, которая должна подтвердить что текущей `CLR` является четвертая версия.